# Is there a way for K8s service account to create another service account in a different namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app which interacts with an existing service account ("the agent") on a designated namespace. I want the agent to be able to create additional service accounts and roles on other namespaces. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: if the role attached to the service account has the permission then I would expect it should be possible.

Comment: But even if I give it a cluster role, according to the docs it will be scoped in the namespace, won't it?

Comment: If a `ClusterRole` is linked to a `ServiceAccount` using a `RoleBinding`, the `ClusterRole` permissions apply to the namespace in which this `RoleBinding` has been created.

If a `ClusterRoles` is linked to a `ServiceAccount` using a `ClusterRoleBindings`, the `ClusterRole` permissions apply to all namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered to this question in a comment section, but I've also decided to provide more comprehensive information with examples.

#### Background

Kubernetes includes **RBAC** ([role-based access control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)) mechanism that enables you to specify which actions are permitted for specific user or group of users. From Kubernetes `v1.6` **RBAC** is enabled by default.

There are four Kubernetes objects: [`Role`, `ClusterRole`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole), [`RoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) and [`ClusterRoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding), that we can use to configure needed **RBAC** rules. `Role` and `RoleBinding` are namespaced and `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` are cluster scoped resources.

We use `Role` and `RoleBinding` to authorize user to namespaced resources and we use `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` for cluster wide resources.
However, we can also mix this resurces.

Below I will briefly describe common combinations.
**NOTE:** It is impossible to link `ClusterRoleBindings` with `Role`.

For every test case I created new `test` namespace and `test-agent` service account.

#### Role and RoleBinding

I created simple `Role` and `RoleBinding` in specific namespace:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: test-role
  namespace: test
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-rolebinding
  namespace: test
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: test-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-agent
```

We can see that `test-agent` has access only to resources in `test` namespace:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n test --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n default --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
no
```

#### ClusterRole and RoleBinding

I created `ClusterRole` and `RoleBinding`:
**NOTE:** I didn't specify any namespace for `ClusterRole`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-rolebinding
  namespace: test
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-agent
```

Now we can see, that if a `ClusterRole` is linked to a `ServiceAccount` using a `RoleBinding`, the `ClusterRole` permissions apply **ONLY** to the namespace in which this `RoleBinding` has been created:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n test --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n default --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
no
```

#### ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding

Finally I created `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`:
**NOTE:** I didn't specify any namespace for `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-clusterrolebinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-agent
  namespace: test
```

Now we can see, that if a `ClusterRole` is linked to a `ServiceAccount` using a `ClusterRoleBinding`, the `ClusterRole` permissions apply to all namespaces:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n test --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n default --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pod -n kube-system --as=system:serviceaccount:test:test-agent
yes
```

---

*Useful note:* You can display all possible verbs for specific resource using
`kubectl api-resources -o wide`, e.g. to display all possible verbs for `Deployment` we can use:

```
$ kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep deployment
deployments                       deploy       apps/v1                           true         Deployment                       [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```

Comment: Absolutely. I will mark it. @matt_j Thanks so much for your time.